# read json and access multiple keys

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am trying to fetch the content of my json file through looping and conditional statements in python.

Here is the JSON file content:

```
{
    "count": 3,
    "result": [
        {
            "type": "first",
            "first": {
                "_links": {
                    "self1": {
                        "href": "/c6a5c1db-cf6e-4b12-9944-a1b6451963d4"
                    },
                    "self2": {
                        "href": "https://example.com"
                    },
                    "ver": {
                        "href": "https://example1.com"
                    }
                },
                "id": "c6a5c1db-cf6e-4b12-9944-a1b6451963d4",
                "tags": []
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "year",
            "year": {
                "month": {
                    "api1": {
                        "href": "https://Ap1.com"
                    },
                    "api2": {
                        "href": "FETCH-CONTENT"
                    },
                    "api3": {
                        "href": "https://Ap3.com"
                    },
                    "api4": {
                        "href": "https://Ap4.com"
                    }
                },
                "idProvider": {
                    "id": "sfsmkfmskf",
                    "name": "Apikey"
                },
                "tags": []
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "year",
            "year": {
                "month": {
                    "api1": {
                        "href": "https://Ap11.com"
                    },
                    "api2": {
                        "href": "FETCH-CONTENT-1"
                    },
                    "api3": {
                        "href": "https://Ap13.com"
                    },
                    "api4": {
                        "href": "https://Ap14.com"
                    }
                },
                "identityProvider": {
                    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                    "name": ""
                },
                "tags": []
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to access the `self2` `href` from the first object and the `api3` `href_1` from the 2nd and 3rd objects. I am able to access `api3` `href_1` if there is no first object and it prints the required keys.

However, when I am printing the content with passing complete file, it fails to print the content. Because it does not get the same keys name for all the objects.

To print

```
print([item['year']['month']['api3'] for item in data['result']])
```

This above line prints the desired data if the json file does not contain the first element of the result array. When I have added the first element of result array it doesn't give any result.

Comment: Not sure I uderstand your problem. Can you please display your python code (or at least a part of it) ? 
Why can't you just do `data = json.loads(your_json_string)` ? 
There data will be the list of your objects (dictionaries in this case).
The way you access elements will depend of the type of objects of course, but that can simply be resolved with if, elif, else statements

Comment: Please show your code.  It is hard to see your issue if you don't show what you did.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse  I am trying to fetch the key and value from json array.However there is inconsistency in the json data . I have updated the question with the code which i tried and it prints the data.

Comment: Is this the entire JSON content, can you also provide your expected output @RJ_Singh ?

Comment: Hi @DeveshKumarSingh, the answer which i have posted gives the fixed field that is we have to explicitly specify which field we want to fetch.                         
                                                                                                                              
My requirement is to store each element of list as an object so that we can fetch the fields of a any element of list without specifying field explicitly.

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh No devesh, it is not the entire json content but the keys are similar for all objects from 2nd json object.

Comment: Can you add a  link to the entire content, and add the expected output, and I can try to run my code against it and see what happens @RJ_Singh

Answer (score 2):

Ignore the item which has `"type": "first"` using the below statement. It works.

`print([item['year']['month']['api3'] for item in data['result'] if "year" in item])`

You can see it in the below example presented.

```
>>> data = {
... "count": 3,
... "result": [
...     {
...         "type": "first",
...         "first": {
...             "_links": {
...                 "self1": {
...                     "href": "/c6a5c1db-cf6e-4b12-9944-a1b6451963d4"
...                 },
...                 "self2": {
...                     "href": "https://example.com"
...                 },
...                 "ver": {
...                     "href": "https://example1.com"
...                 }
...             },
...             "id": "c6a5c1db-cf6e-4b12-9944-a1b6451963d4",
...             "tags": []
...         }
...     },
...     {
...         "type": "year",
...         "year": {
...             "month": {
...                 "api1": {
...                     "href": "https://Ap1.com"
...                 },
...                 "api2": {
...                     "href": "FETCH-CONTENT"
...                 },
...                 "api3": {
...                     "href": "https://Ap3.com"
...                 },
...                 "api4": {
...                     "href": "https://Ap4.com"
...                 }
...             },
...             "idProvider": {
...                 "id": "sfsmkfmskf",
...                 "name": "Apikey"
...             },
...             "tags": []
...         }
...     },
...     {
...         "type": "year",
...         "year": {
...             "month": {
...                 "api1": {
...                     "href": "https://Ap11.com"
...                 },
...                 "api2": {
...                     "href": "FETCH-CONTENT-1"
...                 },
...                 "api3": {
...                     "href": "https://Ap13.com"
...                 },
...                 "api4": {
...                     "href": "https://Ap14.com"
...                 }
...             },
...             "identityProvider": {
...                 "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
...                 "name": ""
...             },
...             "tags": []
...         }
...     }
... ]}
>>> 
>>> print([item['year']['month']['api3'] for item in data['result'] if "year" in item])
[{'href': 'https://Ap3.com'}, {'href': 'https://Ap13.com'}]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to select the records with the correct type like using an `if` in your comprehension like:

```
print([item['year']['month']['api3'] for item in data['result'] 
       if item['type'] == 'year'])
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = {
    "count": 3,
    "result": [
        {
            "type": "first",
            "first": {
                "_links": {
                    "self1": {
                        "href": "/c6a5c1db-cf6e-4b12-9944-a1b6451963d4"
                    },
                    "self2": {
                        "href": "https://example.com"
                    },
                    "ver": {
                        "href": "https://example1.com"
                    }
                },
                "id": "c6a5c1db-cf6e-4b12-9944-a1b6451963d4",
                "tags": []
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "year",
            "year": {
                "month": {
                    "api1": {
                        "href": "https://Ap1.com"
                    },
                    "api2": {
                        "href": "FETCH-CONTENT"
                    },
                    "api3": {
                        "href": "https://Ap3.com"
                    },
                    "api4": {
                        "href": "https://Ap4.com"
                    }
                },
                "idProvider": {
                    "id": "sfsmkfmskf",
                    "name": "Apikey"
                },
                "tags": []
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "year",
            "year": {
                "month": {
                    "api1": {
                        "href": "https://Ap11.com"
                    },
                    "api2": {
                        "href": "FETCH-CONTENT-1"
                    },
                    "api3": {
                        "href": "https://Ap13.com"
                    },
                    "api4": {
                        "href": "https://Ap14.com"
                    }
                },
                "identityProvider": {
                    "id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
                    "name": ""
                },
                "tags": []
            }
        }
    ]
}
print([item['year']['month']['api3'] for item in data['result']
       if item['type'] == 'year'])
```

#### Results:

```
[
    {'href': 'https://Ap3.com'}, 
    {'href': 'https://Ap13.com'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying few more combination, below code worked fine.

```
import json
with open('C:\python\examplee.json', 'r+') as fr:
     data = json.load(fr)
     for item in data['result']:
          if item['type']=='year':
                print([item['year']['month']['api3']['href']])
          else:
               print([item['first']['_links']['self2']['href']])
```